# Passing void * through haskell

Tags: c, haskell

I'm working on a C library ([libpandoc](https://github.com/ShabbyX/libpandoc)) that uses a haskell library (pandoc) to do some work. The C library gives the haskell wrapper callbacks to read and write data. Typical with callbacks, I would also like to send a `void *user_data` so that the callbacks would not have to depend on global variables.

Searching the internet however, I can't seem to figure out how to pass Haskell a `void *` variable.

There is the [CString](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-C-String.html) which is a `char *` (and can eventually be used as a workaround, but it's not so nice) and the general [Ptr](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-Ptr.html#t:Ptr) which makes pointers out of things. However, those things seem not to include `void` (which is also understandable). Looking at [Foreign.C](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-C.html) I don't see anything else that could be useful.

My question is, what type can I use to pass such a function to Haskell?

```
int func(char *buffer, void *user_data);

...

that_haskell_function(..., func, my_data);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any pointer type at all should work, I think, but `Ptr ()` makes the most sense.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign
import Numeric

foreign import ccall unsafe "foo"
    c_foo :: Ptr () -> IO ()

main :: IO ()
main =
    allocaBytes 8 $ \ptr -> do
        c_foo ptr
        x <- peek (castPtr ptr) :: IO Word64
        putStrLn (showHex x "")
```

And the C file:

```
#include <string.h>

void foo(void *ptr)
{
    memset(ptr, 0xEB, 8);
}
```

Gives the result:

```
ebebebebebebebeb
```

Comment: +1 - Agreed, I have used this before to point to generic objects using the FFI.

Comment: Surely Ptr of an uninhabited type (such as, well, `Void` -- though the naming is only a coïncidence) is a much better idea? You wouldn't want to accidentally dereference it. When making FFI bindings, it would probably be even better to define your own uninhabited type, `data Foo`, and then use `Ptr Foo` to keep track of the types.

Comment: @shachaf I'd go for that for reasons of added type safety and self-documenting code, but I don't see how you think someone will accidentally dereference `Ptr ()` - there is no `instance Storable ()`.

Comment: That's true, admittedly -- though someone could add one (but I'm not sure what it would do...). But using an inhabited type for something that never ought be dereferenced just seems bizarre.

Comment: @shachaf: but it isn't actually uninhabited. Haskell doesn't really have an equivalent of data pointed to by `void*` (nor does C have an equivalent of `Void`), though for C _functions_ `T func(void*)` we have the equivalent `forall v . v -> T` (where you can in principle use `UnsafeCoerce` if you know what type will be passed), so I suppose `void*` would be equivalent to the `ImpredicativeTypes` type `Ptr (forall a . a)`. Which is ridiculous.   I'd say `Ptr ()` is just fine.

Comment: Doesn't defining the datatype that the pointer points to and using `Ptr ThatDataType` make even more sense than either `()` or `Void`?

Comment: @BenMillwood I'd say so, and that's what shachaf referred to earlier.

Comment: @BenMillwood, since the Haskell library gets a user-provided callback, the supplementary pointer is not of any particular type, hence the `void *`. That's a common idiom in C w.r.t to callbacks, to allow each caller decide the type that suits them best.